# Query image result change after sometime

Tags: javascript, mysql, animation

I have uploaded a couple of banner images in upload folders and mysql. Now I have to show 4 of them one at a time and will change after some time. Lets say it's like a animation that on load it shows image 1 and after 30 seconds it will show image 2 and so on and so forth. How Can I achieve something like this as I'm not a javscript type of guy so please help me out.

Here's my code.

```
<div class="add_banner">
            <?php
              $now = date("Y-m-d");
              $sql = "SELECT distinct vt_ad_image_path, vd_ad_link_red from tbl_admin_ad WHERE vt_ad_type = 1 and vt_ad_starting_on > '$now' and vt_ad_ending_on > '$now' and vt_ad_status = '0'";
                 $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                  $img_path = $row['vt_ad_image_path'];
                  $img_URL  = $row['vd_ad_link_red'];
                  echo "<a href='".$img_URL."'><img src='".$img_path."' alt='img' style='width:1080px;'/>";
                 }
            ?>

          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to send Ajax requests every time you want another picture? And then już reload img tag src. You can set interval every 30 seconds to Ask for another image's src. 
Onload show and show img with first row of result. In attr data-id f.e. you are showing image's id. Then setting the interval and get data-id of current image. Asking with Ajax for another one and showing it UP for the user. This is the Best idea if you do not want to use some kind of slider

Comment: Need some help with ajax as well. I'm not a fan of jquery and ajax